# Remove nil values from a map?

Tags: clojure

I have a Clojure map that may contain values that are nil and I'm trying to write a function to remove them, without much success (I'm new to this).

E.g.:

```
(def record {:a 1 :b 2 :c nil})
(merge (for [[k v] record :when (not (nil? v))] {k v}))
```

This results in a sequence of maps, which isn't what I expected from merge:

```
({:a 1} {:b 2})
```

I would like to have:

```
{:a 1, :b 2}
```

Answer (score 73, accepted):

your *for* list comprehension returns a LIST of maps, so you need to APPLY this list to the merge function as optional arguments:

```
user> (apply merge (for [[k v] record :when (not (nil? v))] {k v}))
{:b 2, :a 1}
```

More concise solution by filtering the map as a sequence and conjoining into a map:

```
user> (into {} (filter second record))
{:a 1, :b 2}
```

Dont remove *false* values:

```
user> (into {} (remove (comp nil? second) record))
{:a 1, :b false}
```

Using *dissoc* to allow persistent data sharing instead of creating a whole new map:

```
user> (apply dissoc                                                                                            
       record                                                                                                  
       (for [[k v] record :when (nil? v)] k))
{:a 1, :b 2}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the `(filter second ...)` approach does not work. `(into {} (filter second {:a true :b false}))` gives `{:a true}`-

Comment: into uses transients, so despite it not being the same map, it's space efficient

Comment: Would be good to use `val` rather than `second`. `val` makes it easy to see at a glance that record is a sequence of map entries i.e. it is a map.

Comment: This would be slightly more idiomatic: `(into {} (remove (comp nil? val) record))`

Comment: Not only that: using `val` instead of `second` also removes the overhead of implicitly converting each `MapEntry` to a `seq`. Although the better semantic match is usually the stronger argument for `val`.

Answer (score 10):

Here is one that works on nested maps:

```
(defn remove-nils
  [m]
  (let [f (fn [[k v]] (when v [k v]))]
    (postwalk (fn [x] (if (map? x) (into {} (map f x)) x)) m)))
```

Comment: I mean, it works on regular maps, but also when you have e.g. {:foo {:bar nil :baz "ba"}}

Comment: With a map containing all nils, this should really return `nil`. For example, `(remove-nils {:foo {:bar nil :baz nil}})` should return `nil`, but instead returns `{:foo {}}`. How can we modify this answer to address the issue of a map with *all* `nil` values?

Answer (score 9):

A variation on @Eelco's answer:

```
(defn remove-nils [m]
  (let [f (fn [x]
            (if (map? x)
              (let [kvs (filter (comp not nil? second) x)]
                (if (empty? kvs) nil (into {} kvs)))
              x))]
    (clojure.walk/postwalk f m)))
```

To @broma0's point, it elides any empty maps.

```
user> (def m {:a nil, :b 1, :c {:z 4, :y 5, :x nil}, :d {:w nil, :v nil}})
user> (remove-nils m)
{:b 1, :c {:z 4, :y 5}}
user> (remove-nils {})
nil
```

Answer (score 5):

You could squish it into a map:

```
(into {} (remove (fn [[k v]] (nil? v)) {:a 1 :b 2 :c nil}))
=> {:a 1 :b 2}
```

Answer (score 5):

Jürgen Hötzel solution refined to fix the nil/false issue

```
(into {} (filter #(not (nil? (val %))) {:a true :b false :c nil}))
```

A bit shorter version of @thnetos solution

```
(into {} (remove #(nil? (val %)) {:a true :b false :c nil}))
```

Answer (score 3):

Though Jürgen's (filter second record) approach gets my vote for Niftiest Clojure Trick, I thought I'd toss another way out there, this time using `select-keys`:

```
user> (select-keys record (for [[k v] record :when (not (nil? v))] k))
{:b 2, :a 1}
```

Answer (score 3):

reduce-kv can also be used to remove the keys

```
(reduce-kv (fn [m key value]
                (if (nil? value)
                  (dissoc m key)
                  m))
            {:test nil, :test1 "hello"}
            {:test nil, :test1 "hello"})
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one that works on maps and vectors:

```
(defn compact
  [coll]
  (cond
    (vector? coll) (into [] (filter (complement nil?) coll))
    (map? coll) (into {} (filter (comp not nil? second) coll))))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use reduce.

```
user> (reduce (fn [m [k v]] (if (nil? v) m (assoc m k v))) {} record)
{:b 2, :a 1}
```

If for some reason you want to keep the ordering (which is usually not important in a map), you can use `dissoc`.

```
user> (reduce (fn [m [k v]] (if (nil? v) (dissoc m k) m)) record record)
{:a 1, :b 2}
```