# Remove nil values from deeply nested maps

Tags: clojure

Given this map:

```
{:a nil 
   :b {:c nil 
       :d 2 
       :e {:f nil 
           :g 4}}}
```

I need a function to remove all nil values, so that the returned map is

```
{:b {:e {:g 4}
     :d 2}}
```

Or, when given:

```
{:a nil 
   :b {:c nil 
       :d nil 
       :e {:f nil 
           :g nil}}}
```

The result is:

```
nil
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937661/remove-nil-values-from-a-map) has an answer containing a function that supposedly works for nested maps, but that function fails when given a map that is nested more than one level deep.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

modification of answer from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/22186735/1393248

```
(defn remove-nils
  "remove pairs of key-value that has nil value from a (possibly nested) map. also transform map to nil if all of its value are nil" 
  [nm]
  (clojure.walk/postwalk 
   (fn [el]
     (if (map? el)
       (not-empty (into {} (remove (comp nil? second)) el))
       el))
   nm))
```

Comment: And you can change `(filter #(second %) el)` by `(remove (comp nil? second) el)` to handle `false` values, e.g. `{:a nil :b false}` will return `{:b false}`

Comment: @AbbéRésina And if `nil`s are rare, it would be quicker to amend the map than reconstruct it: `(let [m (apply dissoc el (map first (filter (comp nil? second) el)))] ... )`

Comment: thanks for the corrections and suggestions. I have fixed my code to remove only nil valued map entries.

Comment: This does not preserve records unless you use `(and (not (record? el)) (map? el))`. Of course then you accept that nil values of records won't be removed.

Answer (score 1):

```
(defn clean [m]
  (if (map? m)
    (let [clean-val (fn [[k v]]
                      (let [v' (clean v)]
                        (when-not (nil? v')
                          [k v'])))
          m' (->> (map clean-val m)
                  (remove nil?)
                  (into {}))]
      (when-not (empty? m') m'))
    m))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using specter you can do it like this:

```
(declarepath DEEP-MAP-VALS)
(providepath DEEP-MAP-VALS (if-path map? [(compact MAP-VALS) DEEP-MAP-VALS] STAY))

(setval [DEEP-MAP-VALS nil?] NONE  
{:a nil 
  :b {:c nil 
      :d 2 
      :e {:f nil 
      :g 4}}})
```

Please note it will return `:com.rpl.specter.impl/NONE` instead of `nil` if nothing is left.

This is partial reuse of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56299372/53943) answer